# Take $f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, define $g(x) := f (ax + b)$. Compute the Fourier transform of $g$ in terms of that of $f$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

> Suppose that $f$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and define $g(x) := f (ax + b)$. Compute the Fourier transform of $g$ in terms of that of $f$. Does the result hold if we merely assume that $f$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? Specify in which sense you consider the Fourier transform of f .

To solve this exercise I would be tempted to go on like this:

$$\mathcal{F}g(\xi) = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x)e^{-2\pi i x \xi} \ dx = \int_\mathbb{R} f(ax + b)e^{-2\pi i x \xi} \ dx$$

and then I would use the substitution $v := ax + b$.

However this solution seems too simple and it does not distinguish the case $L^1$ from $L^2$ and I think that more importantly we may not be able to use the first equality because that is given only for Schwartz functions (in fact we are asked to say in which way we are considering the transform)..

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925712/fourier-transform-of-hx-fax-b) question on this site but noone said nothing about theese "subtleties".

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works for functions in $L^1,$ where the Fourier transform is just given by that convergent integral. It is in $L^2$ where that formula may fail to hold. There, you define the Fourier transform via a density argument with Schwarz functions, as you mention, and so the proof cannot be done merely using this integration.

To verify the identity in $L^2,$ one must argue that the transformation $f(x) \mapsto f(ax+b)$ is a continuous transformation on $L^2$ when $a\neq 0.$ This is not so difficult to verify once you realize it is what you need to prove. Then, the fact that Schwarz functions are dense in $L^2$, combined with continuity of the Fourier transform and continuity of this mapping, implies the formula in $L^2$ from the formula for Schwarz functions.

Comment: Perfect. I still have a question about some subleties of your answer: you say that the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is *defined* like that convergent itegral. In the theory I've been taught we have defined firstly the Fourier trasform  $\mathcal{F} : S(\mathbb{R}^d) \to L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, then we showed that it is an isomorphism of the Schwartz space (i.e. $\mathcal{F} : S(\mathbb{R}^d) \to S(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with inverse $\mathcal{F}^{-1})$ and finally we said this operator can be extendend to a contraction from $L^1(\mathbb{R} \to C_0(\mathbb{R})$. ..Continues..

Comment: @Gabrielek Ah, if that is how you defined it, then you will need to say some more for the $L^1$ case. You could proceed just as in the $L^2$ case, or you can show that the integral formula holds for all of $L^1$ by noticing that Schwarz are dense in $L^1,$ and then the integration formula is continuous on $L^1,$ so if it the Fourier transform agree on the dense set of Schwarz functions, they must coincide on all of $L^1.$

Comment: I deleted my comment.. aaarrg. About your last comment, just to be clear isn't also $L^2$ dense in $S(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @Gabrielek Well, S(R) is dense in $L^2,$ but yes. This is (part of) why it is possible to define the Fourier transform just from knowing it on the Schwarz functions. (You also need something like Plancherel's theorem to actually do the extension to $L^2,$ as you probably saw in class, which is why extending to $L^p$ in general is not so easy even though Schwarz functions are dense in $L^p$ for $1 \leq p < \infty.$)